# How to solve Bertrand model of duopoly?

Tags: game-theory, economics

Consider a case of differentiated products:

$q_i = 12 - pi + bp_j$ where b > 0

Assume no costs so that:

Profit for firm i = $q_i (p_i, p_j)\cdot  p_i$

Want to maximise the profit function: $[12 - p_i + bp_j] * p_i$

Assuming firms are symmetric: $p_i = p_j = p$

Max: $[12  - p + bp] \cdot  p$

Differentiated: $12 + (2b - 2) \cdot  p = 0$

$p = \frac{12}{  2 - 2b}$

However I'm supposed to have $p = \frac{12} b$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you use both profit functions separately,

$$\Pi_i= [12 - p_i + bp_j] \cdot  p_i$$

Differentiating w.r.t $p_i$ and setting the derivative equal to $0$.

$$\frac{\partial \Pi_i}{\partial p_i}=12-2\cdot p_i+bp_j=0 $$

$$\Rightarrow p_i=6+\frac{b}2\cdot p_j\quad (*)$$

Two options for the next steps:

**1)** You can use the symmetry argument, which means that $p_i=p_j$. We use the reaction function of firm $i$.

$$p_i=6+\frac{b}2\cdot p_i\quad$$

$$p_i\cdot \left(1-\frac{b}2\right)=6\Rightarrow \boxed{p_i=\frac{12}{2-b}}$$

**2)** You can use the reaction function of firm j: $$ p_j=6+\frac{b}2\cdot p_i$$ Combined with $(*)$ you have a small equation system. The solution is the same as in $1)$.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You´re welcome.